# When the condition expression in a if is a command in a bash script, what it means?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, command-line

When I write the bash script like below:

```bash
file_path="/workspace/output.bin"
file_path_="/workspace/output_.bin"

if cmp -s "$file_path" "$file_path_"; then
    continue
fi
```

In my opinion, the condition is the return value of the  `cmp` command, so the if expression above means when `output.bin` and `output_.bin` are different excute `continue`, otherwise skip `continue`.

But in fact, the execution behavior of bash is completely opposite.
When the two files are same, the `continue` will excute. Why?

Or what the if condition means?

Comment: That's how shells work. Exit code `0` means success, i.e. "true". Non-zero exit code means "false". `cmp` exit code is `0` if files are equal.

Comment: You should think of `cmp` as testing "are the files the same", not "are the files different". BTW, the `diff` command follows the same convention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accoring to

`help if`

```
if: if COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; [ elif COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; ]... [ else COMMANDS; ] fi
    Execute commands based on conditional.

    The `if COMMANDS' list is executed.  If its exit status is zero, then the
    `then COMMANDS' list is executed.  Otherwise, each `elif COMMANDS' list is
    executed in turn, and if its exit status is zero, the corresponding
    `then COMMANDS' list is executed and the if command completes.  Otherwise,
    the `else COMMANDS' list is executed, if present.  The exit status of the
    entire construct is the exit status of the last command executed, or zero
    if no condition tested true.

    Exit Status:
    Returns the status of the last command executed.
```

---

So in your case if the exit status of `cmp` is true (zero):

```
cmp -s "$file_path" "$file_path_"
echo $?
```

Should return `0` if they are identical which means `true`

---

If the `cmp` in your system supports the `--help` flag:

```
cmp --help | grep '^Exit status'
```

Output

```
Exit status is 0 if inputs are the same, 1 if different, 2 if trouble.
```

- See [POSIX cmp](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cmp.html)

---

Now according to `help test`

```
help test | grep -F '! EXPR'
```

Output

```
      ! EXPR         True if expr is false.
```

The `!` bang negates, meaning the exit status is reverse.

---

Which means you could do:

```
if ! cmp -s "$file_path" "$file_path_"; then
    continue
fi
```

Otherwise an `elif` or `else` block is needed.

---

The negation using `!` is not limited/attached to the `if` clause/statement, you could do things like:

```
! cmp -s "$file_path" "$file_path_" 
echo $?
```

---

Also the `&&` and `||` works with that expression,

- See `LESS='+/Compound Commands' man bash` if available.
- See `LESS='+/EXIT STATUS' man bash` if avaialble
- See [Exit Status](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html)
- See [Conditional Construct](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html)